# In Scala, how do you convert an Array with n elements into an Array of tuples?

Tags: arrays, scala, collections

How do you convert from an `Array[Int]` of length `n`, into an `Array[(Int,Option[Int])]` of length `Math.ceil(n / 2.0).toInt`?

```
scala> val a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The resultant `Array` for the example above would be `Array((1, Some(2)), (3, some(4)))`.  If `a` were `Array(1)`, then the desired result would be `Array((1, None))`.

Capice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar to Seth's suggestion, just a little more concise.

```
scala> Array(1,2,3,4,5).grouped(2).map(x=> (x.head, x.tail.headOption)).toArray
res17: Array[(Int, Option[Int])] = Array((1,Some(2)), (3,Some(4)), (5,None))
```

Comment: I think Seth's solution is more readable. I'm a fan of shorter lines. :)

Answer (score 4):

`grouped` is useful for breaking the array into pairs, and `case` is useful for dealing with the possibility of a leftover element:

```
def toPairs[T](xs: Array[T]): Array[(T, Option[T])] =
  xs.grouped(2)
    .map{
      case Array(a, b) => (a, Some(b))
      case Array(a)    => (a, None)
    }.toArray

scala> toPairs(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
res0: Array[(Int, Option[Int])] = Array((1,Some(2)), (3,Some(4)), (5,None))
```

Comment: With a risk being nitpicking, I'd suggest it would be more semantically correct to replace `collect` with `map`, because your function under `collect` is not in fact partial.

Comment: I'm marking @jwvh's as the answer.  He edged you, Seth, just barely, based on conciseness, although I did appreciate your answer for clarity.  Thanks to you both!  `grouped` was the gem I was looking for.